# Wagtail form builder e-mail validation error

Tags: validation, wagtail

I use Wagtail form builder. All ok.
but when i fill email field as - 1@1.1 the message is not sent.
If 1@1.dc - its ok, message is sent.
[form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCnY6.jpg)
No error, no validation errors.

How can I do email validation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use one of [Django's form rendering helpers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) such as `{{ form.as_p }}` to display the form on your template, a validation error will be displayed against the invalid email address. If you're not using this, and you're looping over the form fields in your own code instead, your template code needs to check for the presence of an `errors` property on each form field.

For example, your template might look like:

```
<form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <div class="errors">
                {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="field">
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```